# Ajax удаление файла

Tags: jquery, ajax

Удаляю изображения ajax-запросом, все хорошо работает, но при успешном удалении, изображение должно исчезнуть со страницы, однако этого не происходит и приходится обновлять страницу, чтоб изображение пропало. Собственно код (пробовал скрыть через hide() - тоже не работает):

```
$("body").on("click", ".del_button", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clickedID = this.id.split("-"); 
    var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; 
    var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; 

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "", 
        dataType:"text", 
        data:myData, 
        success:function(response){
            $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut("slow"); //ВОТ ТУТ ПРОБЛЕМА
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Ну и связанный с ним код html:

```
{foreach from=$getGoodsImg item=goodsImg}
    <div class="load-img">
        <img src="/{$goodsImg.srcm}" id="item_{$goodsImg.srcm}"/>
        <a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-{$goodsImg.srcm}">Удалить</a>
    </div>                              
{/foreach}
```

Comment: $('#item_'+DbNumberID).remove() ?

Comment: @Cobalt, не, тоже не работает.

Comment: А само изображение находится? И оно не удаляется только из аякс запроса или вообще? И попробуйте воспроизвести поведения на jsfiddle.net будет легче вам помочь.

Comment: @Kasper А точно срабатывает событие Success? Вы уверены?

Comment: @Vartlok, изображение удаляется из БД, всё нормально, единственное надо скрыть изображение после удаления со страницы, но этого не происходит

Comment: @Ruslan, проверил банальным alert'ом, срабатывает

Comment: @Kasper я понимаю что из БД, я про то что если попробовать удить его со страницы не из аякса, удаление сработает или нет?

Comment: @Vartlok, всё, понял ошибку. В id (`id="item_{$goodsImg.srcm}"`) передавалась ссылка на изображение, а не её номер

Comment: @Kasper А как у вас срабатывало удаление по ссылке? Или вы обманули?

Comment: @Ruslan, нет, удаление работало. Сейчас с имитировал код на https://jsfiddle.net/, по ссылке не работает, дал блоку id=12 и сделал удаление 12 блока, всё отработало

Comment: @Kasper на будущее: в подобные (связанные с JS) вопросы нужно вставлять пример итогового (отображаемого в браузере) HTML-кода, а не смесь HTML и чего-то ещё.